# Nativescript move element by 50% and not by 100%?

Tags: android, angular, android-layout, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a simple demo project where :

```
<GridLayout>

    <StackLayout #myStack1 width="100" height="100" translateX="-50" backgroundColor="red" id="bbb">
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout #myStack2 width="100" height="100" translateX="50" backgroundColor="green" id="ccc">
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Notice that `width` and `height` are `100`.

Now let's add `marginTop` to the `green` layout :

```
@ViewChild("myStack2") private myStack2: ElementRef;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myStack2.nativeElement.marginTop =100;
  }
```

But look what happened :

[image]

It moved by `50%` of `100` ( box dimensions are 100) . Why is that ?

**Question:**

Why did that happen and how can I fix my code to actually marginTop `100` ?

I'm not after translateY=100 ( which does show it as expected - I;m after the reason and solution for marginTop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is actually the expected behavior based on your used layout structure.
The thing is that the `StackLayout` used to apply `marginTop` is stretched (no `verticalAlignment` set means that by default the layout will be stretched). 
To overcome this simply apply `verticalAlignment` setting.

For example:

```
<GridLayout>
    <StackLayout  verticalAlignment="top" #myStack1 width="100" height="100" translateX="-50" backgroundColor="red" id="bbb">
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout verticalAlignment="top" #myStack2 width="100" height="100" translateX="50" backgroundColor="green" id="ccc">
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Additional solutions can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5127#issuecomment-348984613)

Comment: [It still shows it at the 50%](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hgKCE.png) . Can you please have a look ? Frustration...

Comment: Updated the snippet with `verticalAlignment="top"`

Comment: If it's stretched - would it be OK to assume that it is by multiplication of 2 ? becuase this : [`this.myStack2.nativeElement.marginTop =   (100)*2;` does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVyg.png)  (`without verticalAlignment`)

Comment: Nick - however  , using your solution makes it appear at the top : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B9hK.png - and not in the middle. Anyway to mitigate this ?